# How to debug (network file system) nfs module in user mode linux

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs, user-mode-linux

I have setup the user mode linux kernel with the help of one video tutorial in youtube i.e.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6n9id4qnN4.

Now i am able to debug kernel function sys_clone but my actual requirement is to debug nfs module in kernel.

How to setup nfs in user mode linux and debug the nfs module.

when from the symbol table I give as breakpoint one of the functions from nfs module, the break point is never reached.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add break points to nfs_read/write function and see

Comment: I tried to add break points to nfs functions but the nfs commands are not working to configure nfs and to perform operations on nfs .

Comment: Did you enable NFS config in kernel?

Comment: Yes i enabled nfs config.Can you please explain how to use nfs and debug it in UML.

Comment: http://www.cs.uoi.gr/~gkappes/files/tutorials/root_nfs.pdf

Comment: Can we SSH to running UML kernel?

Comment: You need to create interface to do ssh. Search for networking on UML